# Http HEAD returning different Last-Modified dates on different servers for same resource, why?

Tags: linux, http, curl

We have a Java process that fetches resources over HTTP.  I discovered that one resource was not pulling correctly even after a client had modified it.  Digging into it I found that on the server the process is running the Last-Modified date of the resource does not match what I see when I view info from a browser.  I then tried fetching it from a different server and my laptop and both of those showed the correct date.

I've since patched the process to allow the option to Ignore the header date for cases when it exists (but will be incorrect) but I would really love to know why this happens.

For reference here is a curl response from the Server that returns the incorrect info.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1
Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 14:16:57 GMT
Content-length: 132
Content-type: text/plain
Last-modified: Wed, 15 Sep 2010 21:58:20 GMT
Etag: "84-4c91417c" 
Accept-ranges: bytes
```

And then the same request on a different server (also get the same results on my machine)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1
Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 14:18:47 GMT
Content-length: 132
Content-type: text/plain
Last-modified: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 01:20:43 GMT
Etag: "84-4e7bdeeb"
Accept-ranges: bytes
```

Both servers are running on Fedora 10.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me and how I might be able to fix this long term?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 servers and both return different results, i.e. inconsistency problem (I can basically see this from Etag header)?

My first guess would be caching. Are the any caches active? Maybe the invaliation of cache doesn't work correctly or ttl (time-to-live) settings are too long.

As test have a try and fresh restart machine with stale data and see whether results change (usually during restart of systems most of the simple cache-setups are flushed).

Which kind of backend does the resource come from initially (database, file-system, 3rd party-service)?

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been busy and didn't checkup on this.  I'm unfamiliar with any caching running on the server in question, I'll have to try and dig in to see.  Do you know of any services that would be running by default on a Linux machine. As for the resource in question it is just a text file on a file system hosted on a third parties web server.

Comment: what kind of file-system is it (networking one like NFS)? How are you accessing the file? I wonder why Sun-ONE-Web-Server is used. By default usually most linux distributions come with Apache. Did you install it yourself? Maybe you can tell more of your requirement (are you simply "tunneling" through file-contents through HTTP)?

Comment: It is coming from a Sun web server because the file we are pulling is hosted on a 3rd party's website.  It is just a text file that exists somewhere on their web server.  As I mentioned we have a Java process that reads this file periodically, however even when I use CURL to pull the files header info from the command line I get the same old header date.  So this can't have anything to do with Apache I don't think, it isn't even running on that server.  I was thinking maybe you meant there is some generic caching process that is a linux process I might not be familiar with.

Comment: there is no generic caching mechanism in linux I would be aware of. I would have a look at the server. Maybe you can try to restart the server, if then the content is consistent/up-to-date then most likely there are some caching setting inside the server itself. Maybe there is preset ETag handler and caching configuration.

Comment: I had a chance to restart the instance this morning.  Unfortunately I am still seeing the old Last-modified date.  Quite odd.  At least I have a work around in place :)